# Postgres usage of format()

Tags: sql, postgresql, format, plpgsql

Is the usage of format() in cases like this generally interchangeable?

```
exec_str := format('UPDATE ' || TG_ARGV[0] || 
                    ' SET username = current_user,
                              time = current_timestamp::timestamp(0);'
                  );
EXECUTE exec_str;
```

vs.

```
exec_str := 'UPDATE ' || TG_ARGV[0] || 
                    ' SET username = current_user,
                              time = current_timestamp::timestamp(0);'
                  ;
EXECUTE format(exec_str);
```

Comment: Did you try each?

Comment: yes, both work. I just would like to know if one of the variants could produce errors. I just did not have any problems so far. Better be safe than sorry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary benefit of the function `format()` is that you can use parameters:

```
execute format('
    UPDATE %I 
    SET username = current_user,
        time = current_timestamp::timestamp(0);',
    TG_ARGV[0]);
```

Read more in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use [`EXECUTE ... USING ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `USING` can only bind values, not identifiers (like in the original question).