# Optimize sql query on postgresDB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have around 700 tables in my DB.When I run the script below, it takes almost 1 hour. How can I optimised this query?

Database: Postgres

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    tables_list CURSOR FOR
        select distinct t_name, t_schema from information_schema.columns 
 where column_name = 'deleted_flag' 
    and t_schema='customer' and t_name not like 'v_%';
BEGIN
    FOR t_record IN tables_list LOOP
        EXECUTE 'update ' || t_record.table_schema || '.' ||      t_record.table_name || ' set deleted_flag=false';
    END LOOP;
end;
$$;
```

At the end, all the tables in this schema should have this field deleted_flag as false. I have to run this script very often on production environment. Grateful if someone can help how to optimise this script.

Do you think if add a check in the where clause,

```
EXECUTE 'update ' || t_record.table_schema || '.' ||      t_record.table_name || ' set deleted_flag=false where deleted_flag=true';
```

the execution time will be less?

Comment: Strong advice not to use string concatenation. Use the`FORMAT()` function instead (which handles mixed case and embedded whithespace in identifiers)

Comment: do you have an example? does it work with postgres?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39204821/905902

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make this really efficient.

Here are a few pointers what you can do to make it faster:

- You should definitely add `WHERE deleted_flag` to the query to avoid unnecessary updates.
- If there are only few rows where `deleted_flag = true`, you can create a partial index like this:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON atable ((1)) WHERE deleted_flag;
  ```
- If there are too many rows to make a partial index useful, create the tables with `fillfactor = 50` and make sure that there is no index on `deleted_flag`.

  Then you can enjoy HOT update which is much cheaper.
- Set `max_wal_size` high enough that you don't end up with too many checkpoints.
- Get enough RAM so that the whole database fits in memory.
- Get fast storage.

But I think that your design is weird, and the best solution would be to find a way to avoid these regular updates.

Comment: `follfactor`? You mean `fillfactor`, don't you?

Comment: I meant `foolfactor`. No, seriously - fixed. Thanks.